# Managing DB migrations on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, database-migration

I have a Kubernetes based application consisting of multiple services (and pods) managed with helm chart.

Postgres is used as a database for all services.

When application is upgraded to a newer version, I am running a db migration script via `initContainers`.

The problem occurs when migration scripts require an exclusive access to DB (all other connections should be terminated), otherwise the script is blocked.

Ideal solution would be to stop all pods, run the migration and recreate them. But I am not sure how to achieve it properly with Kubernetes.

Tnx

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of DB migrations are requiring the database to be unused?

Comment: Modifying trigger functions, altering types, etc (we have complicated db structure).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Ideal solution would be to stop all pods, run the migration and
> recreate them. But I am not sure how to achieve it properly with
> Kubernetes.

I see from one of the comments that you use Helm, so I'd like to propose a solution leveraging Helm's hooks:

> Helm provides a hook mechanism to allow chart developers to intervene
> at certain points in a release's life cycle. For example, you can use
> hooks to:
>
> - Load a ConfigMap or Secret during install before any other charts are
>   loaded.
> - Execute a Job to back up a database before installing a new
>   chart, and then execute a second job after the upgrade in order to
>   restore data.
> - Run a Job before deleting a release to gracefully take a
>   service out of rotation before removing it.

https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/

You could package your migration as a k8s `Job` and leverage the `pre-install` or `pre-upgrade` hook to run the job. These hooks runs after templates are rendered, but before any new resources are created in Kubernetes. Thus, your migrations will run before your Pods are deployed.

To delete the deployments prior to running your migrations, create a second pre-install/pre-upgrade hook with a lower `helm.sh/hook-weight` that deletes the target deployments:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "pre-upgrade-hook1"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-1"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: "pre-upgrade-hook1"
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      serviceAccountName: "<an SA with delete RBAC permissions>"
      containers:
      - name: kubectl
        image: "lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:latest"
        command: ["delete","deployment","deploy1","deploy2"]
```

The lower hook-weight will ensure this job runs prior to the migration job. This will ensure the following series of events:

1. You run `helm upgrade`
2. The helm hook with the lowest hook-weight runs and deletes the relevant deployments
3. The second hook runs and runs your migrations
4. Your Chart will install with new Deployments, Pods, etc.

Just make sure to keep all of the relevant Deployments in the same Chart.

Comment: Actually I was looking on hooks especially on `pre-upgrade`. I was thinking to somehow delete the relevant deployments during this stage and let helm recreate them during upgrade. Yet I am not sure how to play with deployment from k8s job. I'd like to solve it within the scope of a single helm chart instead of creating multiple charts.

Comment: Hi @Miro, I added a possible solution to delete the relevant deployments prior to running the migrations as a separate helm-hook job, which uses hook-weight to sort multiple hooks.

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I was looking for! Looks very promising - starting to check it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Works perfectly well for now.

Answer (score 3):

From an automation/orchestration perspective, my sense is that problems like this are intended to be solved with Operators, using the recently released Operator Framework:

https://github.com/operator-framework

The idea is that there would be a Postgres Migrations Operator- which to my knowledge doesn't exist as yet- which would lie idle waiting for a Custom Resource Definition describing the migration to be posted to the cluster/namespace.

The Operator would wake up, understand what's involved in the intended migration, do some analysis on the cluster to construct a migration plan, and then perform the steps as you describe-

- put the application into some kind of user-visible maintenance mode
- take down the existing pods
- run the migration
- verify
- recreate the application pods
- test
- take the application out of maintenance mode

That doesn't help you now, though.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Yet, I think it is not right to blend applicative logic (i.e. db migration) and orchestration logic (terminate pod, do work, recreate pod). It feels to me that Kubernetes (or some higher level orchestrator) should support "updateContainers" which are similar to "initContainers". It will also be helpful to be able specifying explicit orchestration instructions (i.e. "delete selected deployments" / "create selected deployments") instead of trying to achieve the same we custom made containers having delegated permissions.

Comment: Agreed that the specific nature of database migrations make them unique. There is a tight binding between specific database versions and specific application versions that mean that there has to be some application-specific coordination. But I think the shape is worth considering. There are other operational activities that such an Operator would automate- at minimum backups, restores, failovers, then perhaps scale ups and downs- which would also involve having some knowledge of service dependencies be explicitly available, from which lifecycle operations could be derived.

Answer (score -1):

> Ideal solution would be to stop all pods, run the migration and
>   recreate them. But I am not sure how to achieve it properly with
>   Kubernetes.

This largely depends on your approach, specifically on your CI/CD tools. There are several strategies that you can apply, but, as an illustration, presuming you have Gitlab pipeline (Jenkins could do the same, terminology is different, etc) here are the steps:

- Make following stages in gitlab-ci.yaml:

  - **Build** (where you create all necessary images and prepare migrations prior to anything deployed)
  - **Stop all** affected assets - deployment, services, statefulsets (this can be done as rather simple kubectl delete -f all_required_assets.yaml, where in single manifest you have defined all resources you want stopped completely. You can set grace period as well or force termination and you don't need to remove static assets - only related to stopping. Note that to stop pods you need to remove their top level creation resource, being it pod, deployment, replication controller or statefulset to stop them completely, not simply restart)
  - **Migrate** implemented either as Job or as Pod that would handle migrations with database (say, kubectl create -f migrate_job.yaml). Preferable job for error tracking after job finishes.
  - **Start all** assets (same manifest file with affected resource definitions as for stop stage, say, kubectl create -f all_required_assets.yaml, and all start/stop resources are handled through single file. If start order is important for any reason, then separate file is required, but with careful considerations one file should suffice for most scenarios)

This same principle can be exercised in other orchestration/deployment tools as well, and you can even make a simple script to run those kubectl commands directly in one go if previous one is successful.

Comment: Actually we do use Gitlab CI, yet k8s deployments are managed with helm, which is responsible for organizing many kinds of different services/deployments into a single application. Gitlab CI is good when you have a single application. In our case we have multi-tenant scenario - each customer has it's own instance of an application with all the relevant services and db. Is there any external system which can support multiple concurrent pipelines  (per customer) of a kind you mentioned? (with ability to easily add/remove pipeline)

Comment: This is a bit different question but helm can be viewed as templating system for manifests files. This begs three questions: 1) do you have separate database pod per customer (or just separate database on one pod that handles all customers)? 2) If separate db pods, do you migrate on all customers or just some of them? 3) Do you have pods that are making actual connection to database(s) and their corresponding creation resources properly labeled (say with label such as - ondbmigrate: stop)?

Comment: 1) dedicated database and pods per customer. 2) for simplicity, let's assume a single job that migrates all apps together. 3) It's surely possible to label them this way

Comment: You have several option depending on how you introduce new customers. But, your helm charts should be divided so all connection related resources should be in one chart. Then helm delete <resources_chart> should terminate all those at once. Next you run migration job and recreate with helm install. Another illustration with labels could be  to kubectl get deploy,pods... -l <label> --all-namespaces -o yaml > all.yaml, separate with awk or sed per resources and delete all, then recreate. All depending on actual complexity.